# How to sync two column code?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to synchronize the two columns (one table, two columns).

Example:

`A-1 references B-2, 3, 4` but `A-2 references only B-1`.

How to add B-1 reference B-3 and B-4 with mysql query?

```
A    B 
-------
1    2
1    3
1    4
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    6
5    7
6    5
7    5
```

Comment: Post the query you've attempted so far. SO is not a free coding service. We can help you with issues you're facing in your code, but we won't code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
insert into t(a, b)
    select b, a
    from t
    where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.a = t.b and t2.b = t.a);
```

This will put all pairs into the table, in both directions.